# Fade animation not working properly when used with other animation

Tags: codenameone

I combine the a component sliding component with other component fade animation. But the component appears for a second before it fades in. Here the form is in Layered layout. Since there are other components as well that overlap each other. All works fine but the ones i apply fade in have the same issue. I have attached the gif of how it looks below.

[image]

beforeSplash(Form f) :

```
f.setLayout(new LayeredLayout());
Container bottomContainer = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
f.add(FlowLayout.encloseBottom(bottomContainer));

Container appleContainer = new Container(new FlowLayout(Component.CENTER, Component.BOTTOM));
appleLabel = new Label(apple);
appleLabel.setVisible(false);
appleContainer.add(appleLabel);

bottleLabel = new Label(bottle);

bottomContainer.add(appleContainer);
bottomContainer.add(bottleLabel);
bottleLabel.setVisible(false);
```

postSplash(Form f) :

```
bottleLabel.setVisible(true);
arrangeForSlide(bottleLabel);
bottleLabel.getParent().animateLayoutAndWait(2000);

appleLabel.setVisible(false);
appleLabel.setVisible(true);
appleLabel.getParent().animateLayoutFadeAndWait(2500, 0);
f.revalidate();
```

Slide animation:

```
private void arrangeForSlide(Label c) {
    c.setX(-c.getWidth());
}
```

Update:

```
    bottleLabel.setVisible(true);
    arrangeForSlide(bottleLabel);
    bottleLabel.getParent().animateLayoutAndWait(2000);
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            Display.getInstance().callSerially(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    appleContainer.setVisible(true);
                    appleContainer.animateLayoutFadeAndWait(2000, 0);
                }
            });
        }
    }.start();
```

Now i need to add other components animation after above applecontainer animation finishes and so on. eg:

```
  questionBg.setVisible(true);
  questionBg.getParent().animateLayoutFadeAndWait(3000, 20);
```

Update 2:

I added only one component appleLabel and applied fade effect and the result is the same. so may be it is not EDT issue. I have tried it in barebone template too.

```
  Container appleContainer = new Container(new FlowLayout(Component.CENTER, Component.BOTTOM));
  appleLabel = new Label(apple);
  appleContainer.add(appleLabel);
  appleLabel.setVisible(false);
  f.add(appleContainer);
  f.show();
  appleLabel.setVisible(true);
  appleLabel.getParent().animateLayoutFadeAndWait(5000, 0);
```

It doesnt work so I have tried in callSerially but it gives same issue as well

```
  Display.getInstance().callSerially(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
          appleLabel.setVisible(true);
          appleLabel.getParent().animateLayoutFadeAndWait(5000, 0);
        }
```

Comment: I don't understand what isn't working here? The code looks reasonably fine. Can you capture a video (ideally from the simulator and ideally in slow motion mode).

Comment: I saw the gif now. It animates only once so it's somewhat hard to see what is going on and replay it.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `appleContainer` to visible false too and see if this helps.

Comment: I had already tried it but with same result. If i remove the horizontal (slide) of the bottleLabel, the fade effect is quite good. But with it, the effect is as in the gif. PS in gif the fade in isnot seen but in devices, the apple flashes abruptly for a sec and then only fade in occurs. I dont want to show the apple before fade in effect.

Comment: Is this the first screen of the application? Did you try it in slow motion mode?

Comment: yeahh, this is my first screen. In slow motion the component flashes and is not shown.

Comment: Try starting the animation in a callSerially call.

Comment: call serially works. But i have more components for the animation how to include them as well. I have updated the code above thankyou

Comment: You don't need the thread. Just the `callSerially`. Move everything into the call serially rather than just those lines.

Comment: Sorry it is not working. I tested the fade effect in only one component apple label, the problem still exist. So callserially might not solve the problem. I have updated (update 2) the issue above please have a look.

Comment: Can you separate this into a test case that we can run and see the issue?